# Vue.js - how to have multiple inputs in a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have just started learning Vue.js and I am trying to get the values from my components. Is there a way to have multiple input fields in my component and get the value of each outside of the component?

For example, if I wanted to get and change the value for both of my input fields in my simple-input component. Right now they both have the same value but I would like to have 2 different values in each input.

**My component**

```
Vue.component('simple-input', {

    template: `
        <div>
            <input type="text" :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
            <input type="text" :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
        </div>
    `,

    props: ['value']

});
```

**main.js**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#root',

    data: {
        value1: 'Initial value 1',
        value2: 'Initial value 2',
        value3: 'Initial value 3'
    },

    methods: {
        alertSimpleInput1() {
            alert(this.value1);
            this.value1 = 'new';
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<simple-input v-model="value1"></simple-input>
<simple-input v-model="value2"></simple-input>
<simple-input v-model="value3"></simple-input>

<button @click="alertSimpleInput1">Show first input</button>
```

Comment: You could use an array for each value instead of a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to have different values for each input you have two choices:

1. set two props rather one for each component and assign each prop to one input.
2. use one input for each components (with one prop) and use different components for get different inputs.

first implementation:

```js
Vue.component('simple-input', {

    template: `
        <div>
            <input type="text" :value="value1" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
            <input type="text" :value="value2" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
        </div>
    `,

    props: ['value1','value2']

});

new Vue({
    el: '#root',

    data: {
        value11: 'Initial value 11',
        value12: 'Initial value 12',
        value21: 'Initial value 21',
        value22: 'Initial value 22',
        value31: 'Initial value 31',
        value32: 'Initial value 32'
    },

    methods: {
        alertSimpleInput1() {
            alert(this.value11);
            this.value11 = 'new';
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <simple-input :value1="value11" :value2="value12"></simple-input>
  <simple-input :value1="value21" :value2="value22"></simple-input>
  <simple-input :value1="value31" :value2="value32"></simple-input>
  

  <button @click="alertSimpleInput1">Show first input</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for! I am still trying to understand how it all works.

Comment: I see my mistake was using v-model instead of :value1 and :value2

Comment: but it is error-prone, this component usage is not very common and probably correct, think differently and check [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) again !

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do better once I understand the basics. This example was very useful. Still trying to understand why we need @input="$emit('input' ....

Comment: But it wont update component props. how can we do that?